# Show that K and complement to K are "1-reducible" to EQ={⟨x,y⟩|φx≃φy}

Tags: computability

Where $K = \{x | φ_x(x) \downarrow\}$, $φ_x$ is a $\mu$-recursive function computing $M_x$, $M_x$ is Turing machine with Godel's number $x$.  Set $A$ is "1-reducible" to set $B$ ($A \leq_1 B$) when there exists invertible function $f = (\forall x \in N)[x \in A \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in B]$.

I need that for part of my homework. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note: "1-convertible" is more commonly called "[1-reducible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction)".

Comment: @QuinnCulver for $1$-reducibility, $f$ also needs to be a total recursive function—something you proved in your answer but isn't made clear in the question.

Comment: @BenedictEastaugh You're right. Presumably this is what the OP had in mind (otherwise the solution would be trivial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the [s-m-n theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smn_theorem), define a 1-1 function $g(x)$ such that

$$
\varphi_{g(x)}(n) =
\begin{cases}
 1 &\text{if } \varphi_{x}(x)\downarrow,\\
 \uparrow &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Let $e$ be such that $\varphi_{e}(n) =1$ for each $n$. The function $f(x) = \langle e, g(x) \rangle$ is then computable and 1-1. Moreover, 
$$x \in K \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in \mathrm{EQ}.$$